# Função usando como argumentos valores sucessivos de uma coluna (R)

Tags: r, data.frame, funções

Tenho um `data.frame` com 13 colunas e 78 linhas. Preciso fazer para cada coluna `((x1/x2)^12)-1`, sendo `x1` o valor contido na primeira linha da primeira coluna, `x2` o valor contido na segunda linha da primeira coluna, e preciso aplicar esta função para todas as linhas. Para automatizar o processo eu pensei em utilizar a função `rollapply`, o problema está na elaboração da função. Como posso, no r, usar os valores sucessivos de uma coluna como argumentos de uma função?

Comment: "sendo x1 o valor contido na primeira linha da primeira coluna, x2 o valor contido na segunda linha da primeira coluna, e preciso aplicar esta função para todas as linhas".  Aqui você quis dizer que precisa aplicar a função para todas as colunas, certo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o `sapply` junto com o `mapply`. Fazendo com um `data.frame` de exemplo:

```r
set.seed(1)
dados <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100))
resultados <- sapply(dados, function(col) mapply(function(x1, x2) ((x1/x2)^12)-1, 
                                  x1=col[1:(length(col)-1)], 
                                  x2=col[2:(length(col))]))
```

Explicando um pouco melhor o código, o `mapply` vai aplicar a função `function(x1, x2) ((x1/x2)^12)-1` usando como `x1` os elementos de 1 até n-1 e como `x2` os elementos de 2 até n. E o `sapply` vai fazer como que essa função percorra todas as colunas do seu `data.frame`. O resultado será, portanto, uma `matrix` com o mesmo número de colunas do `data.frame` original mas com uma observação a menos:

```r
head(resultados)
                 x             y
[1,]  2.482943e+06  1.043354e+14
[2,] -1.000000e+00 -1.000000e+00
[3,] -9.995733e-01  1.345669e+09
[4,]  1.658279e+08 -1.000000e+00
[5,] -9.999824e-01 -9.999933e-01
[6,]  5.163748e+02  5.053287e+04
```

Comment: Carlos, muito obrigado. Era isso mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

A solução usando o `rollapply`seria:

```
require(zoo)
set.seed(1)
dados <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100))
rollapply(dados, FUN = function(x) (x[1]/x[2])^12 - 1, width = 2, align = 'r')
```